# how to prevent special HTML characters being interpreted into symbols

Tags: javascript, php, html

If some special html characters are retrieved with AJAX POST, Like `&hearts;`

how to display them on front pages as normal ones but not symbolized.

here is [Some special HTML character sample](http://www.degraeve.com/reference/specialcharacters.php).

Comment: I'm not sure which you want. Do you want to display ♥, or &hearts;?

Comment: the &hearts; string not the heart shape

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML encode the HTML entity. The HTML entity for the special character & is `&amp;`.
So the HTML encoding for &hearts; is `&amp;hearts;`.

Comment: I'm using htmlspecialchars within php.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to encode all the special characters (such as `&`), [here is a jquery function that will do it for you](http://api.jquery.com/text/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use strreplace and then replace it with image,html symbols or anything

Answer (score 0):

You can call below function:

```
function htmlEncode(value){
if (value) {
    return jQuery('<div />').text(value).html();
} else {
    return '';
}}
```